# Sony Remote Camera SDK demo app unable to connect to Sony FX3

Tags: sony, sony-camera-api

I am writing a small app to remotely control Sony full-frame cameras. Everything works fine for the *Sony A7C (ILCE-7C)* and *Sony A7RIV*, however, my app has issues with connecting to the *Sony FX3 (ILME-FX3)*. The demo app that came with the Sony Camera Remote SDK release is also unable to connect to the FX3:

```
RemoteSampleApp v1.05.00 running...

Remote SDK version: 1.5.00
Initialize Remote SDK...
Working directory: CrSDK_v1.05.00_20211207a_Mac_original/build/Release
Remote SDK successfully initialized.

Enumerate connected camera devices...
Camera list is null? True
CR_FAILED(enum_status) False
No cameras detected. Connect a camera and retry.
Program ended with exit code: 1
```

Here are the relevant lines in the source code:

```
    cli::tout << "Enumerate connected camera devices...\n";
    SDK::ICrEnumCameraObjectInfo* camera_list = nullptr;
//     auto enum_status = cr_lib->EnumCameraObjects(&camera_list, 3);
    auto enum_status = SDK::EnumCameraObjects(&camera_list, 10);
    if (CR_FAILED(enum_status) || camera_list == nullptr) {
        cli::tout << "Camera list is null? "<< (camera_list == nullptr ? "True": "False") << std::endl;
        cli::tout << "CR_FAILED(enum_status) "<< (CR_FAILED(enum_status) ? "True": "False") << std::endl;
        cli::tout << "No cameras detected. Connect a camera and retry.\n";
        // cr_lib->Release();
        SDK::Release();
        std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    auto ncams = camera_list->GetCount();
    cli::tout << "Camera enumeration successful. " << ncams << " detected.\n\n";
```

The *Remote SDK demo* app recognizes the *Sony A7C* and *Sony A7RIV* camera, so I think the USB-C cable and the ports on my laptop are working fine:

```
RemoteSampleApp v1.05.00 running...

Remote SDK version: 1.5.00
Initialize Remote SDK...
Working directory: CrSDK_v1.05.00_20211207a_Mac_original/build/Release
Remote SDK successfully initialized.

Enumerate connected camera devices...
Camera enumeration successful. 1 detected.

[1] ILCE-7C (D01060399BD8)

Connect to camera with input number...
input>
```

The Sony Imaging Edge - Remote app recognizes the *Sony FX3* and works as expected, so i assume that the USB-C port on the *Sony FX3* is working properly and the settings are correctly set in the camera menu
PC Remote -> on
PC Remote Cnct. Method -> USB
[image: Sony Imaging Edge - Remote]

Any ideas on what could be the problem?

Platform and version info:
Sony A7C - ILCE-7C - firmware v2.00
Sony A7RIV - ILCE-7RM4 - firmware v1.20
Sony FX3 - ILME-FX3 -  firmware v1.01.
Sony Camera Remote SDK v1.5 (v1.05 on the website)
RemoteSampleApp v1.05.00
OS: Mac OS 12.4 Monterey
Xcode and compiled for x86_64 (Rosetta)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only a handful of camera models are currently supported according to the [Camera Remote SDK](https://support.d-imaging.sony.co.jp/app/sdk/en/index.html) info web page. Although the *Sony FX3* is very similar to the *Sony A7S III*, the FX3 doesn't connect and A7S III connects successfully.

```
Supported device
ILCE-1, ILCE-9M2, ILCE-7RM4A, ILCE-7RM4, ILCE-7SM3, ILCE-7M4, ILCE-7C
DSC-RX0M2 (Ver. 3.00 or later)
```

Edit: With the introduction of the Sony FX30 camera, Sony updated the SDK and now supports the FX lineup.

"Added support for ILME-FX6V/ILME-FX6T(Ver. 3.00 or later), ILME-FX3(Ver. 2.00 or later) and ILME-FX30."

Answer (score 0):

Please note that FX3 is now supported with the new release of [Camera remote SDK](https://support.d-imaging.sony.co.jp/app/sdk/en/index.html)